# Gvim on Windows 7: ALT codes not working

Tags: gvim

I would like to be able to enter <kbd>ALT</kbd> codes in Gvim on Windows 7 as documented on the following site:

[Alt Codes](http://www.alt-codes.net/)

> On Windows (Windows 7 in my case), to generate a character via an <kbd>ALT</kbd>
>   code you make sure that the NumLock key on your keypad is toggled on,
>   hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, enter the keycode on the numeric keypad,
>   and then release the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key.

However this does not work in Gvim on Windows (which ignores the fact
that I am pressing the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and just prints to entered keypad key
directly onto the screen). How can I get these keystroke combinations
to work in Gvim as well? Thanks.

---

EDIT:

As the answer below points out, the way to insert non-ASCII characters for which you
do not have entries on your keyboard without changing the keyboard layout is as follows:

Make sure you are in insert mode, and then type CTRL-V followed by
the Unicode character code of interest, for instance:

```
CTRL-V u00E0    (generates à)
CTRL-V u00C8    (generates È)
CTRL-V u00E8    (generates è)
CTRL-V u00E9    (generates é)
CTRL-V u00EC    (generates ì)
CTRL-V u00F2    (generates ò)
etc...
```

See for instance http://unicode-table.com/ for a full list of Unicode character codes.

The following list of Unicode characters by language may also be useful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

In some cases such as this one, though, there might be an easier
way to enter special characters (see :help digraphs and :digraphs).
For example, while in insert mode you may be able to type the following:

```
CTRL-K E! (yields É)
CTRL-K a' (yields á)
```

Note that as the following page shows:
http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/doc/digraph.txt
Gvim 7.4 contains an even wider set of default digraphs than Gvim 7.3,
thus providing convenience to an even broader set of languages.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those shortcuts are a Windows input mechanism. I don't believe gvim uses that Windows system (for consistency if nothing else). To enter arbitrary characters in gvim you can use the gvim unicode input support :h i_ctrl-v (specifically :h i_ctrl-v_digit).